# Request access to Instagram API endpoints- review status not updated

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have developed a social media management app which can be used by my customers on business purpose. For that app i have enabled my customers to connect with various social media networks including instagram. To get access with POST methods of instagram, we need to submit the app for review by filling [this](https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116) form. I have submitted my app for review, but didn't get any response for the instagram team/ facebook team. How long it will take them to review an app? How can i know my app review status whether reviewing/approved/rejected? Or from who can i get that information? Anyone help me to find this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How To Submit - Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#newsubmission)
If you look at the step 5, you can read "The review time estimate will change based on the requested permissions, ranging between 3 to 7 business days."
So be patient, it will happen quickly !

Comment: Instagram states that they will begin reviewing app submissions made after Nov 17th, 2015 on Dec. 3rd, 2015.  Still no word from them on my app submission as of Dec. 16th.

Comment: Unfortunately, these things happen. There is sometimes a difference between what people say and what they do... And it's possible that they have a lot of app to review, so it can take more time than usually. Try to contact their developer support

Comment: The link you copied here is for Facebook developers not Instagram review team .